# API Twitch comprobar si un stream esta online

Tags: javascript

tengo algun problema para crear una extensión, necesito saber si un canal de twitch esta online.

Un amigo me ayudo, ya que en lenguaje de marcado soy nulo, con este php.

Pero no sé si quiera si se puede aplicar a web.

```
<?php
$streamChannel = "mastersonothing";  
$url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams?channel=mastersonothing"
$clientid = "12345678901234"

$json_array = json_decode(curl($url), true);  

$newurl = $url . "&client_id=" . $clientid;

if(isset($json_array['streams'][0]['channel'])) {  
echo "<div id='streamonline'>Stream is Online</div>";  
} else {  
echo "<div id='streamoffline'>Stream is Offline</div>";  
}  

?>
```

El problema, viene que no sé si se puede usar igual en js, y a su vez, funcionaria de manera correcta, ¿Alguien me podria ayudar a hacer esta comprobación simple?

Comment: Bienvenido para enteder mejor el funcionamiento del sito te invito a dar [tour]

Answer (score 2):

En la de [documentacion](https://dev.twitch.tv/docs/v5/reference/streams/) Twitch, dice como hacerlo, te dejo el código para realizar la llamada con **Jquery**.

Se necesitan dos parametros: el `client-id` y el `chanlel-name` que es lo mismo que el nombre de usuario.

```
var endpoint = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";
var channelname= "c9sneaky";

$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: endpoint + channelname,
 headers: {
   'Client-ID': clientid
 },
 success: function(data) {
   console.log(data);
 }
});
```

Dependiendo de si esta en vivo o no, devuelve un tipo de **JSON** u otro.

En caso de que **este en vivo**:

```
{
    "stream": {
        "_id": 28311073152,
        "game": "League of Legends",
        "viewers": 19530,
        "video_height": 1080,
        "average_fps": 60,
        "delay": 0,
        "created_at": "2018-04-13T03:05:36Z",
        "is_playlist": false,
        "stream_type": "live",
        "preview": {
            "small": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_c9sneaky-80x45.jpg",
            "medium": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_c9sneaky-320x180.jpg",
            "large": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_c9sneaky-640x360.jpg",
            "template": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_c9sneaky-{width}x{height}.jpg"
        },
        "channel": {
            "mature": false,
            "partner": true,
            "status": "COGGERS (Twitch Prime)",
            "broadcaster_language": "en",
            "display_name": "C9Sneaky",
            "game": "League of Legends",
            "language": "en",
            "_id": 24538518,
            "name": "c9sneaky",
            "created_at": "2011-09-02T23:16:11Z",
            "updated_at": "2018-04-13T07:34:08Z",
            "delay": null,
            "logo": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c9sneaky-profile_image-03d2c6cbb19c9e5d-300x300.png",
            "banner": null,
            "video_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/c9sneaky-channel_offline_image-19723bab4c7f1146-1920x1080.png",
            "background": null,
            "profile_banner": "https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/jtv_user_pictures/a9c5b05f-e590-4ebd-b52a-4904512e96f9-profile_banner-480.jpg",
            "profile_banner_background_color": "",
            "url": "https://www.twitch.tv/c9sneaky",
            "views": 79363893,
            "followers": 1186853,
            "_links": {
                "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky",
                "follows": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky/follows",
                "commercial": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky/commercial",
                "stream_key": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky/stream_key",
                "chat": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/chat/c9sneaky",
                "features": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky/features",
                "subscriptions": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky/subscriptions",
                "editors": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky/editors",
                "teams": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky/teams",
                "videos": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky/videos"
            }
        },
        "_links": {
            "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/c9sneaky"
        }
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/c9sneaky",
        "channel": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/c9sneaky"
    }
}
```

Y en caso de que el canal **no este en vivo**:

```
{
    "stream": null,
    "_links": {
        "self": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/shiphtur",
        "channel": "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/shiphtur"
    }
}
```